# Delete Azure DevOps project from Azure Portal

Tags: azure, azure-devops

I created a DevOps project from AzurePortal and it appears in both Portal and DevOps site.

I deleted from DevOps site, and it still appears in my Azure Portal.

Any way to delete it from Portal too?

Comment: what if you click on it and click delete in the new blade?

Comment: What did you have tried? you could just delete it from portal.

Comment: @GeorgeChen that was my question. How do I delete it? There is not 'delete' button anywhere. Since I've deleted it from the DevOps site, clicking on the project from the Portal will give me invalid link. Also, I just checked : The project has now disappear from my Portal woohoo. Took a whole day for the deletion from DevOps site to reflect back on the Portal...

Answer (score 0):

If you delete project from DevOps site and you still could see it from portal please refresh your portal or wait some time, there is probably a delay.

And if you want to delete it from portal, just go to your project resource there should be a Delete button or a More button.

[image]

[image]

Or go to your Resource Group the project exists, you could delete the project there.

[image]